# Does comprehension behave *differently* inside an exec call within a function's body?

Tags: python, scope

In our code, comprehensions are sometimes called from an exec inside a function's body. The behavior however, is not similar to other calls to comprehension:

```
foo = 1
bar = [i for i in (0,) if foo]
print(bar)
```

-> `[0]`

```
LIST_COMPREHENSION = \
"""
foo = 1
bar = [i for i in (0,) if foo]
print(bar)
"""

exec(LIST_COMPREHENSION)
```

-> `[0]`

```
def f():
    foo = 1
    bar = [i for i in (0,) if foo]
    print(bar)
f()
```

-> `[0]`

```
def g():
    exec(LIST_COMPREHENSION)
g()
```

->

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0cc9a6403ba4> in <module>
      1 def g():
      2     exec(LIST_COMPREHENSION)
----> 3 g()

<ipython-input-2-0cc9a6403ba4> in g()
      1 def g():
----> 2     exec(LIST_COMPREHENSION)
      3 g()

<string> in <module>

<string> in <listcomp>(.0)

NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Comment: `exec` is commencing a fresh process. Processes don't share scope/memory/resources/etc. If you start a new process you need to make sure it has `bar` defined.

Comment: @El. But you can see this line:  `exec("""print('bar' in locals())""")` and it suggests bar is defined. That is the question.

Comment: As already mentioned, `exec` execute the code in a fresh process. so the `locals` in the code section point to the freshly commenced process, not the altered(parent) process.

Comment: @El.
Wait, when you run this:
`def foo():
    bar = 'x'
    exec("""print('bar' in locals())""")
foo()`

You get True (not False)

Comment: No, It's `true`. It's thoroughly weird behavior. :)) my guess is that the process gets the locals in the code section as a regular dictionary but not the one that is on the process scope like the `bar` at the last line.

Comment: Check this one:

`def g():
    exec("""
foo = 1
bar = [i for i in (0,) if foo]
print(bar)
""")
g()` Will put it in the quesiton

Comment: Contrary to what the other user is claiming, `exec` does not launch a new process. You can pause execution during `exec` and examine the `ps` output if you want to confirm.

Comment: `def g(): exec(LIST_COMPREHENSION, {})` works (or even with `globals()`-dict) but be sure to run it in a clean and fresh context to avoid possible conflicts with other variables

Comment: @cards why does:
`def g():
    exec(LIST_COMPREHENSION, {}, {})
g()`
fail?

Comment: @AturSams yes, it fails with double `{}`... it seems to be a scoping problem: if you try as mentioned in my previous comment you will see that the `foo` and `bar` variables doesn't belong to the scope of `g` (`locals()` is empty even after `exec`!) but to the globals only. So with `exec(..., {}, {})` the scopes are set to empty